# Installing Jekyll Windows 10 (I think Jekyll was updated so cacert.pem youtube videos no longer work)

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to install Jekyll on my x64 windows 10 computer. I have tried both chocolatey and the normal install but I keep getting the same SSL error:

The installation page and you tube videos no longer work to install Jekyll, so how do I get it with its new release?

Comment: It wont let me post my error because I do not have enough reputation

Comment: Can you edit the question?

Answer (score 1):

you first should install Ruby and Rubygems. Afterwards you can simply install jekyll as gem:

`gem install jekyll bundler jekyll-feed minima sass`

Note: probably the SSL error is related to this topic: 
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1736#issuecomment-261862935